# How can I stop calls to the database for each image request? [finished]

Tags: javascript, express, google-oauth, passport.js

Passport with Google Auth is authenticating each image request to my server.

Authentication calls `passport.deserialize()`

To deserialize I call my database and pull the user profile here:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

per the docs here:

http://www.passportjs.org/docs/

Comment: Do you need to limit the access to the images in any way?  I mean to say, do you care if unauthenticated users get to your images?

Comment: Yes, for every project that needs authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't care about your images being secured, the easiest way to do this is to just not have passport authenticate those routes. It's important to remember that the order of `.use()` statements is significant.

Consider:

```
// this will not get authenticated
app.use(express.static('public'));

// All routes setup after this will get authenticated using the local strategy. 
app.use(passport.authenticate('local'));
```

Comment: Same thing, have Morgan added to the middleware stack after your static middleware.  Or else define it only on certain url patterns.